# borrowing logic when subtracting bigger binary numbers from smaller numbers

Tags: binary

how does borrowing 1 bit logic works when subtracting 0110 from 0000? there is nothing to borrow. Iam not using 2s complement method or anything, only the borrowing bit 1 method

### 0000
-0110

### 1010

tried borrowing from an imaginary 5th bit but the nswer doesnt seem to be right

Comment: Since you cannot directly subtract 1 from 0, you need to borrow from the next higher place value. Start from the rightmost digit and work your way to the left. In this case, you need to borrow 1 from the leftmost digit, so it becomes 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Kunal, but the leftmost digit here is zero, so where does it get its 1 from? thats what is the tricky part here. do we assume an imaginary 1 there in the 5th bit?

Answer (score 0):

When you work with sign numbers, there is sign bit at the beginning. And you need to sum sign bits too. (1 for negative numbers, 0 for positive numbers)

In this case

```
0 0000 (0)
1 1010 (-6) +
-------------
1 1010 (-6)
```

Which means result will be -6